# running e2e testing with aurelia cli

Tags: e2e-testing, aurelia

I'm trying to implement a few e2e tests in my aurelia-cli app. I've tried looking for docs or blogs but haven't found anything on e2e setup for the cli. I've made the following adjustments to the project.

first I added this to `aurelia.json`

```
"e2eTestRunner": {
    "id": "protractor",
    "displayName": "Protractor",
    "source": "test/e2e/src/**/*.ts",
    "dist": "test/e2e/dist/",
    "typingsSource": [
      "typings/**/*.d.ts",
      "custom_typings/**/*.d.ts"
    ]
},
```

Also added the e2e tasks on `aurelia_project/tasks`:

e2e.ts

```
import * as project from '../aurelia.json';
import * as gulp from 'gulp';
import * as del from 'del';
import * as typescript from 'gulp-typescript';
import * as tsConfig from '../../tsconfig.json';
import {CLIOptions} from 'aurelia-cli';

import { webdriver_update, protractor } from 'gulp-protractor';

function clean() {

  return del(project.e2eTestRunner.dist + '*');

}

function build() {

  var typescriptCompiler = typescriptCompiler || null;

  if ( !typescriptCompiler ) {

    delete tsConfig.compilerOptions.lib;

    typescriptCompiler = typescript.createProject(Object.assign({}, tsConfig.compilerOptions, {
      // Add any special overrides for the compiler here
      module: 'commonjs'
    }));

  }

  return gulp.src(project.e2eTestRunner.typingsSource.concat(project.e2eTestRunner.source))
    .pipe(typescript(typescriptCompiler))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(project.e2eTestRunner.dist));

}

// runs build-e2e task
// then runs end to end tasks
// using Protractor: http://angular.github.io/protractor/
function e2e() {

  return gulp.src(project.e2eTestRunner.dist + '**/*.js')
    .pipe(protractor({
      configFile: 'protractor.conf.js',
      args: ['--baseUrl', 'http://127.0.0.1:9000']
    }))
    .on('end', function() { process.exit(); })
    .on('error', function(e) { throw e; });

}

export default gulp.series(
  webdriver_update,
  clean,
  build,
  e2e
);
```

and the e2e.json

```
{
  "name": "e2e",
  "description": "Runs all e2e tests and reports the results.",
  "flags": []
}
```

I've added a `protractor.conf` file and `aurelia.protractor` to the root of my project

protractor.conf.js

```
exports.config = {
  directConnect: true,

  // Capabilities to be passed to the webdriver instance.
  capabilities: {
    'browserName': 'chrome'
  },

  //seleniumAddress: 'http://0.0.0.0:4444',
  specs: ['test/e2e/dist/*.js'],

  plugins: [{
    path: 'aurelia.protractor.js'
  }],

  // Options to be passed to Jasmine-node.
  jasmineNodeOpts: {
    showColors: true,
    defaultTimeoutInterval: 30000
  }
};
```

aurelia.protractor.js

```
/* Aurelia Protractor Plugin */
function addValueBindLocator() {
  by.addLocator('valueBind', function (bindingModel, opt_parentElement) {
    var using = opt_parentElement || document;
    var matches = using.querySelectorAll('*[value\\.bind="' + bindingModel +'"]');
    var result;

    if (matches.length === 0) {
      result = null;
    } else if (matches.length === 1) {
      result = matches[0];
    } else {
      result = matches;
    }

    return result;
  });
}

function loadAndWaitForAureliaPage(pageUrl) {
  browser.get(pageUrl);
  return browser.executeAsyncScript(
    'var cb = arguments[arguments.length - 1];' +
    'document.addEventListener("aurelia-composed", function (e) {' +
    '  cb("Aurelia App composed")' +
    '}, false);'
  ).then(function(result){
    console.log(result);
    return result;
  });
}

function waitForRouterComplete() {
  return browser.executeAsyncScript(
    'var cb = arguments[arguments.length - 1];' +
    'document.querySelector("[aurelia-app]")' +
    '.aurelia.subscribeOnce("router:navigation:complete", function() {' +
    '  cb(true)' +
    '});'
  ).then(function(result){
    return result;
  });
}

/* Plugin hooks */
exports.setup = function(config) {
  // Ignore the default Angular synchronization helpers
  browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;

  // add the aurelia specific valueBind locator
  addValueBindLocator();

  // attach a new way to browser.get a page and wait for Aurelia to complete loading
  browser.loadAndWaitForAureliaPage = loadAndWaitForAureliaPage;

  // wait for router navigations to complete
  browser.waitForRouterComplete = waitForRouterComplete;
};

exports.teardown = function(config) {};
exports.postResults = function(config) {};
```

and I added a sample test in my `test/e2e/src` folder it doesn't get executed. I've also tried implementing a e2e test within the unit test folder since when I run `au test` I see that a chrome browser opens up.

```
describe('aurelia homepage', function() {  
  it('should load page', function() {
    browser.get('http://www.aurelia.io');
    expect(browser.getTitle()).toEqual('Home | Aurelia');
  });
});
```

But this throws the error `browser` is undefined. Am I missing something with e2e testing with the cli? I know aurelia-protractor comes pre-installed but I don't see any way to run it.

Comment: From what I've read on Gitter (on 12/12/2016), the CLI doesn't support e2e testing and people have suggested using JSPM.  I'm not sure if an e2e setup in the CLI is in the works.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a very late answer, but perhaps for others looking for an answer, you could try to import from the aurelia-protractor plugin

```
import {browser} from 'aurelia-protractor-plugin/protractor';
```